# In nim language, how to search for the index of the first appearance of an object

Tags: seq, nim-lang

Newbie in nim here.
While experimenting in nim, I didn't find a `proc` to be able to find the first occurrence of an item in a sequence.

What I practically want to do is, given a `seq`, to remove the first instance of a known `string`, and return the same sequence, with the item removed. So I was thinking, to break it in a two-step work: first find the index and then remove the item at the specific index.

Of course I can write my own helper function for this, but I am surprised that I couldn't find in the `system` or `sequtils` modules any similar solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would just be:

```
var s = @["a", "b", "c"]

s.del(s.find("b"))
```

The `del` function modifies the sequence in place. You would start with a copy of the sequence if you want a new value.

Comment: Note that `del` takes the last item and put it in the place of the removed item, if order matters.